# Setting loop counter in Nasm assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

How do i tell the loop to loop x amount of times. For example loop 10 times. At the moment it loops only twice.

```
loop: 
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, ask
    mov edx, askLength
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, edi
    mov edx, 3
    int 0x80

    add edi, 3; Loop change

    cmp edi, input+6 ;
    jl loop  ; Loop again
```

Answer (score 2):

It compares edi to input+6 and adds 3 each time. 6/3=2. You need to change the `cmp edi, input+X` line appropriately, but it appears this is a buffer, so make sure it is big enough to hold the amount of data you are retrieving.

Comment: thank you, I have changed it to input+30 and it accepted 10 inputs!

Your a wiz!